# Java Dynamic Programming Triggers

Tags: java, dynamic, triggers

Lets say i want to write dynamic code:

### Warcraft 3 Trigger system:

```
Event: if a unit levels
  Condition: if ( triggeringUnit is alive ) && ( triggeringUnit.name="something" )
```

### Java

```
for ( Unit triggeringUnit : leveledUnits )
{
  condition1 = new IsAliveCondition(triggeringUnit);
  condition2 = new HasNameCondition(triggeringUnit);
  if ( new AndCondition( condition1 , condition2 ).isTrue() )
  {

  }
}
```

**Problem :**
This code runs if the code is written statically, however it cannot be formed dynamically. condition 1,2 require a "specific unit" in their constructor, 
in order to be created, thus they are impossible to store in the memory (since they cannot be created). this problem exists because:
condition 1,2 doesn't know it is going to be inside a "for-loop",
neither that there is a variable "triggeringUnit" in that scope.

To solve that problem should i create a hashmap with all variables in scope ?

---

```
Hashmap<String, Object> variables = ... ;
   condition1 = new IsAliveCondition("triggeringUnit");
   condition2 = new HasNameCondition("triggeringUnit");
   condition = new AndCondition( condition1, condition2);

   //At Runtime
   for( Unit triggeringUnit : leveledUnits )
   {
      variables.put("triggeringUnit", triggeringUnit );
      if ( condition.isTrue() )
      {

      }
   }
```

Is there a better solution / design pattern that this ?

Comment: also this question is more broad. For example if i have an ability that deals 100 dmg (static), it could be rewritten to refer to a variable of the hashmap thus a user could modify its power.

Comment: You could look into using a scripting language. Java comes with a bunch of APIs for integrating them and a Javascript implementation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Comment: but scripting languages are static just like java.
I will have to manually rewrite conditions from start each time = code duplication, with my previous solution i would define a set of basic conditions that will be used to define abilities, these will be imported from xml.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish, I thought you wanted a way to process some user-defined triggers. It's just that my first idea when you said "hashmap storing a variable scope" was "that's what scripting languages do".

Comment: Also, why would you have to rewrite conditions from start? Just like you're proposing `Condition` objects in Java, you could use regular functions in JS. You can compose those by writing / generating JS that uses the basic conditions.

Comment: could you write the above example in a scripting language ? just to make sure we are talking of the same thing.

Comment: In my example code is defined with composition pattern.
In a scripting language code is defined by creating a complete new code from start.

Comment: You would have a predefined function `function isAlive(unit) { … }` and `function hasName(unit) { … }` that return booleans. These could be loaded from XML, a JS file, or defined in Java. Then the condition definition would be the following in JS: `isAlive(unit) && hasName(unit)`. You can load the predefined functions into a script engine and evaluate the composed condition using [`eval()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)). The point is to avoid having to reinvent an unreadable version of boolean expressions.

Comment: Also scripting langauges require to write code in text.
Using the composition pattern you could write code in a gui.

Comment: @MadMax Which is not a use case you have mentioned so far. I'd suggest you make your original question complete and clear instead of trickling out additional information as you go.

Comment: ok, i am going to test scripting to see their capabilities, maybe i am mistaken of using composition pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a little like you're looking for [Business Rules Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRMS). Those systems allow the formulation of rules, either using a GUI or kind of scripts, and can be interfaced with languages (often java) in order both to provide more capabilities to the rules and to let a program call the rules engine.

The best known free and open-source BRMS is [DROOLS](http://www.jboss.org/drools/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally this calls for some Publish / Subscribe mechanism, or the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) as the GOF calls it. Create an event type hierarchy and fire events whenever anything happens, letting Observers subscribe to the supported events.

here's a rudimentary first draft:

```
interface EventListener<X extends EventType>{
    processEvent(Map<String, Object> data);
}

public class EventDispatcher{
    private Map<EventType, Collection<EventListener<?>> listeners; // initialize this
    public <X extends EventType> void addListener(X type, EventListener<X> listener){
        // add listener to map
    }
    public void dispatchEvent(EventType type, Map<String, Object> data){
        if(listeners.containsKey(type){
            for(EventListener<EventType> listener: listeners.get(type)){
                listener.processEvent(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when a level up event occurs, your data map would contain the alive and name stats of the unit that levelled up.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic conditions you can use dynamic languages. Below is snippet in Groovy, that can be run in Groovy Console.

```
class IsAliveCondition {
    def triggeringUnit

    boolean isCase() {
        triggeringUnit.alive
    }
}

class HasNameCondition {
    def triggeringUnit
    def name

    boolean isCase() {
        triggeringUnit.name == name
    }
}

class MyUnit {
    def alive
    def name
}

def condition = '''
new IsAliveCondition(triggeringUnit: triggeringUnit) && 
new HasNameCondition(triggeringUnit: triggeringUnit, name: 'somename').isCase()
'''

def leveledUnits = [new MyUnit(alive: true, name: 'somename'), new MyUnit(name: 'Joe')]

leveledUnits.each { triggeringUnit ->
    def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding([triggeringUnit: triggeringUnit]))
    if (shell.evaluate(condition)) {
        println "Condition for <$triggeringUnit.name> satisfied: $condition"
    }
}
```

You see, condition here is just hardcoded string. But it could be as easily read from a file. `Binding` is kind of hash map that you've used, but it is provided by Groovy.

Of course, there are a lot of another dynamic languages for JVM: Jython, JRuby, JavaScript are major ones. They usually intercommunicate with Java relatively simple. For instance, `IsAliveCondition` and `HasNameCondition` could be as well written in Java (they would need constructor and getters/setters as well as type information in this case).